# How to send rating value with click event without form

Tags: angular, parameter-passing

I am having the following dialog which has a **rating system with 10 stars.** I want to send the **value of the filled stars**, as a **number** with the **click event** to the **typescript file** so I can send it through http request to the database.

```
<h2 mat-dialog-title>Rate sitter {{ sitter.firstname }} {{ sitter.lastname }}</h2>
<mat-dialog-content class="mat-body-1">
  <ngb-rating [(rate)]="currentRate">
    <ng-template let-fill="fill">
      <span class="star" [class.filled]="fill">&#9733;</span>
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-rating>
  <hr>
  <pre>Rate: <b>{{currentRate}}</b></pre>
</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>Cancel</button>
  <button mat-button (click)="rateSitter()" [mat-dialog-close]="true">Rate</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

How can I do this **without** needing to put it inside a **form** ? What should I pass as an **argument** to the **click event's function**?

Answer (score 0):

you can use (rateChange)

```
<ngb-rating
    [(rate)]="rating"
    [starTemplate]="t"
    [readonly]="readOnly"
    [max]="max"
    (hover)="isRating = true; hovered = $event"
    (leave)="isRating = false; hovered = 0"
    (rateChange)="onRateChange($event)">
</ngb-rating>
```

and create your function that will get your rate value

```
onRateChange(rating :number) {        

    // save or send your rating value

}
```